# How can i zoom out in Firefox?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have tried to zoom out with follow code:

```
 window.onload = function () {
     var currFFZoom = 0.99;
     var currIEZoom = 90;

     if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Firefox') != -1 && parseFloat(navigator.userAgent.substring(navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Firefox') + 8)) >= 3.6) { //Firefox
         var step = 0.02;
         currFFZoom -= step;
         $('body').css('MozTransform', 'scale(' + currFFZoom + ')');

     } else {
         var step = 2;
         currIEZoom -= step;
         $('body').css('zoom', ' ' + currIEZoom + '%');
     }

 };
```

It works in Chrome, but in Mozilla Firefox it doesn't. What Should I do?

Comment: @PatrickEvans It's working [here](http://jsfiddle.net/YKmrE/2/) even wtih camelcasing. I suspect jQuery knows how to handle it.

Comment: Yea seems i was having some random error, it wouldnt let me use anything but `-moz-transform` when testing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change `curFFZoom` from .99 to .90 like this:

```
window.onload = function () {
     var currFFZoom = 0.90;
     var currIEZoom = 90;

     if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Firefox') != -1 && parseFloat(navigator.userAgent.substring(navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Firefox') + 8)) >= 3.6) { //Firefox
         var step = 0.02;
         currFFZoom -= step;
         $('body').css('MozTransform', 'scale(' + currFFZoom + ')');

     } else {
         var step = 2;
         currIEZoom -= step;
         $('body').css('zoom', ' ' + currIEZoom + '%');
     }

};
```

If you don't the zoom is too small to notice.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jdwire/YKmrE/2/

Comment: The Chrome Zomm out is Okay ... But Firefox Zooms out bad.

Comment: @PersianBoy It is zooming to 88% because of the `-=step code`. If you want it to zoom to 90%, remove that. Can you be more specific about how the zoom out in Firefox is bad?

Comment: @Persian boy if you're talking about the text overlapping the image, I don't know that there's much you can do about that, as that would be a Firefox problem. Maybe you need to find a different solution than zooming out.

Comment: except 2 buttons another controls are image . here is chrome zooming out : http://imageupload.co.uk/files/bc6fx0emx8zi636alq1x.jpg

Comment: Chrome zooming out is what i want .

Comment: @PersianBoy I think that's just the way Firefox is. Until it supports the zoom property, I don't think there's much you can do.

Answer (score 0):

You could also just use CSS to zoom on page load:

```
body { zoom: .9; -moz-transform: scale(0.9); -moz-transform-origin: 0 0 }
```